# Sin and Cos Functions returning incorrect results

Tags: objective-c, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting value of sine 180 as 1.22465e-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566512/getting-value-of-sine-180-as-1-22465e-16)

I am calculating a point on the circumference of the circle. I have the radius and the center point of the circle.
Here you would say, big deal, there is a direct formula for the same.
Yeah, angle is in rad

```
x = x + r*sin(angle)
y = y + r*cos(angle)
```

Okay, now the problem here is even though i am passing angle in radians. Yet I dont get correct answers for the below mentioned angle

```
for 90 degree (rads = 1.5708) i get y axis = -4.3774e-08
for 180 degree (rads = 3.14159) i get x axis = -8.74228e-08
for 270 degree (rads = 4.71239) i get y axis = 1.19249e-08
for 360 degree (rads = 6.28319) i get x asix = 1.74846e-07
```

I am converting Degree to Radians with

```
return degrees * M_PI / 180;
```

I am not sure as to why this is happening.
There must be something seriously wrong.

Here is code used for conversion

```
float angle = DegreesToRadians(90);

float x = sin(angle);
float y = cos(angle);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "objective-c"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`M_PI` is defined in "math.h" as

```
#define M_PI        3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```

which is only *approximately* the (irrational) number Pi. Therefore

```
cos(M_PI/2), sin(M_PI), cos(3*M_PI/2), sin(2*M_PI)
```

are only *approximately* zero. Pi cannot be represented exactly as a `float` or `double`.

From your output I assume that you used `float`.
Since the number of significant digits of a `float` is about 7, and the slope (first derivative) of `sin()` and `cos()` at that points is `+/- 1`, I would say that the results are as good as you can expect.  Working with `double` would give better results, but not exactly zero.

So there is nothing *seriously* wrong, you just can't expect the result of a floating point computation to be exact.

Comment: So what do you guys suggest, not using float.
What data type i use? Since, when i calculate for 45 degree it calculates perfectly fine.

What should be done to get the exact results?

Comment: @Kunjal: The result *is exact* within floating point precision. And there is no alternative to floating point for trigonometric functions. - If you just want to display some points then this is no problem at all, because the result will be rounded to pixels anyway. - Otherwise you have to state more clearly what you do with the results, and why the result is a problem for you.

Comment: There is a circle and I need to place buttons at different angle on the circumference of the circle.

When I use the formula mentioned in my original question, the results that I get will need to be manipulated. If I can get exact results, then its always better to make a CGPoint.

I hope things are clear.

Comment: @Kunjal: I do not yet understand why you have to manipulate the results. Finally you are going to draw at some (integer) pixel position, therefore a difference of -4.3774e-08 does not matter at all. I am sorry if I don't understand your problem correctly, but in my opinion this is no problem.

Comment: let me give it a try, I will update my finding and results!!!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kunjal: Did you make any progress? Please let me know if you need more information about this.

Comment: Hi Martin, apologies since I was on holidays!!! 
Your suggestion did work perfectly fine...

Answer (score 1):

To add a comment to a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100144/java-math-cosmath-toradiansangle-returns-weird-values/13100229#13100229) question...

One alternative is to use grads or degrees instead of radians, so that the multiples of full circles, as well as multiples of each quadrant are integers and also the sines and cosines of *those* arguments can be represented exactly.

Also one has to marvel how well some implementations of math libraries handle multiples of pi: as the representation of pi in floats or doubles is off from the true value by some small amount *delta*, then it follows that N*(pi+-delta) is off from the true value by N*delta. Consequently in a well written library sin((pi/2)+(2*pi)*n) increases with n; with poorly written library, the argument is evaluated modulo *approximation* of 2*pi, giving exactly the same offset for every *n*.

Comment: The question that you did refer is for java. Will the same work for Objective-c? Also, I am not sure if Objective-C allows to do calculations in grads or degrees

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is more or less language independent -- and so is the art of dividing circle to integer number of sectors. The latter is probably useful in limited cases only and where the trigonometric functions are performed with look up tables.

Answer (score 0):

In general when dealing with floats it is not advisabe to compare the results (for equal) with any specific number, may that be 0, 1 or even pi or e. 
-8.74228e-08 is close enough to be treated as 0 in pracically all computable cases. (If not, then you have a significance issue with float/double anyway)

In the event that you need to compare them in program code, you should rather substract the values and compare the result with < or > and some very small number. e.g.

```
if (sin(something*pi) < 0.0001f) ...
```

rather than

```
if (sin(something*pi) == 0) ...
```