# Trigonometric functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, trigonometry

I'm beginner developer for iOS. I use some online tutorials to learn Swift and now I'm trying to develop my own calculator. There is task to down "sin" and "cos" buttons by my own, which would return sine or cosine function for entered value.

Of course, there is sin() and cos() functions in the Swift, but I've found, that it returns values in radians, not degrees. I did search and found code, smth like that

```
func sind(degrees: Double) -> Double {
return sin(degrees * M_PI / 180.0)
}
```

which I implemented in my code. Now everything looks fine, buttons returns correct values. But there is sine of 180 degrees is 0 and when I enter 180 in my calculator and press "sin" button it returns another value. Same for cosine of 90 degrees, should be 0 but returns another value.

Could you please explain how possible to fix it? Full code at github: https://github.com/senator14/firstcalculator.git

Comment: What are the values you are getting instead?

Comment: Do you get very small non-zero values, like 1.22e-16? That is the usual floating point inaccuracy. But have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600210/1187415 for an alternative implementation.

Comment: @MartinR you explained this with obj-c, does it the same with swift also?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13846297/4126633

Comment: @DanielKrom: (Objective-)C and Swift use the same floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @MartinR thank you. I've read this tread before. I tried your method, but, unfortunately, couldn't get _sinpi function. I tried to import Darwin and Cocoa and math.h but nothing helped :(

Comment: @Senator14: Did you try the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600210/1187415? It compiles without problems in my Xcode projects.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I tried, but when I use _sinpi() function Xcode says "Use of unresolved identifier '_sinpi'

Comment: @Senator14: `__sinpi` has *two* underscores. Just copy/past the code from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600210/1187415 into your ViewController.m, it should compile without problems!

Comment: @MartinR yes, I got it, just wanted to type it manually to remember it better :) Thank you very much indeed for your responce, __sinpi() works just great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with sine and cosine functions is that M_PI is an irrational number is approximately defined as `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288` which means that it has some error.

One possible solutions to your problem is having the ranges of input form -PI/2 to PI/2. This reduces the error of approximation. The following changes your range to -90 to 90 degrees.

```
sin(((fmod($0, 360) > 270 ? fmod($0, 360) - 270 : ((fmod($0, 360) > 90) ? 180 - fmod($0, 360) : fmod($0, 360))) * M_PI / 180.00)) }
```

Reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566525/2082521)

Comment: Thank you @meteors! This worked for me. I understood the issue, now trying to understand the code. However, how it should work for cosine? Shall range for cosine be from -180 to 180 degrees? Is that correct? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Senator14 No. Range of cosines should also be from -90 to 90. If that doesn't work try 0 to 180.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the same fom -90 to 90 for cosine but it didn't work. I will try to make it 0 to 180. Thank you again indeed