# RPN calculator (Swift xcode) - sine, cosine, tangent, reciprocal (1/x), log (base) functions

Tags: swift, math, rpn

I have build a basic RPN calculator with Swift and I need to add those functions: sine, cosine, tangent, reciprocal (1/x), log (base) & log (base10). 
Here is the code that I have for the basic operations:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CalculatorEngine: NSObject
{
    var operandStack = Array<Double>() //array

    func updateStackWithValue(value: Double)
    { self.operandStack.append(value) }

    func operate(operation: String) ->Double
    { switch operation

    {

    case "×":
        if operandStack.count >= 2 {
            return self.operandStack.removeLast() * self.operandStack.removeLast()
        }


    case "÷":
        if operandStack.count >= 2 {
            return self.operandStack.removeFirst() / self.operandStack.removeLast()
        }


    case "+":
        if operandStack.count >= 2 {
            return self.operandStack.removeLast() + self.operandStack.removeLast()
        }

    case "−":
        if operandStack.count >= 2 {
            return self.operandStack.removeFirst() - self.operandStack.removeLast()
        }

    case "√":
        if operandStack.count >= 1 {
            return sqrt(self.operandStack.removeLast())
        }

    default:break
        }
        return 0.0
    }
```

Comment: That's a math question, not a programming one

Comment: but what are the basic operation. because when I enter
case "sin":
    if operandStack.count >= 1 {
        return sin(self.operandStack.removeLast())
    }

it doesnt give me the same result as a basic calculator so i do not thing it is the right function that i use but I do not know which one to use

Comment: What? Do you receive radians instead of degrees? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32046853/trigonometric-functions-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of those basic functions in Swift.  I'll let you put that into your RPN calculator, since that is your assignment.

The built-in trig functions need input in radians, so you have to convert by multiplying by `pi` and dividing by `180.0`.

```
func sine(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return sin(degrees * M_PI / 180)
}

func cosine(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return cos(degrees * M_PI / 180)
}

func tangent(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return tan(degrees * M_PI / 180)
}

func log(n: Double, base: Double) -> Double {
    return log(n) / log(base)
}

func reciprocal(n: Double) -> Double {
    return 1.0 / n
}
```

For log(base 10) just use the built-in `log10(n: Double) -> Double`